# Can I use an else tag while data-linking top-level elements in JsViews?

Tags: javascript, jsrender, jsviews

Is it possible to use else tag when data linking to top level elements in JsViews?

If so where do you put the else tag in an example like this?

```
<tbody class="movies" data-link="{for movies tmpl='movieTmpl'}"></tbody>

<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <tr class="hover" data-link="css-background-color{:~bgColor()}">
    <td>
      <span data-link="#index + 1"></span>:
      <span data-link="title"></span>
    </td>
    <td data-link="{for languages tmpl='languageName'}"></td>
    <td>
      <img class="removeMovie"
        src="http://www.jsviews.com/resources/images/close.png" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Support for `{else}` in data-link expressions is available since commit 62.

The syntax is:

`data-link="{for movies tmpl='movieTmpl'}{else tmpl='noMoviesTmpl'}"`

or - for `if/elseif/else` semantics:

`data-link="{if expr1 tmpl='ifTmpl'}{else expr2 tmpl='elseifTmpl'}{else tmpl='elseTmpl'}"`

There is a jsfiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/Lerwt6ya/

(See https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/issues/293 for related some discussion and context.)

Comment: I have updated the reply with a link to working example - now that this feature is available on JsViews.